# Google Sheets Error

Tags: php, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

> Fatal error: Uncaught Google_Service_Exception: { "error": { "code": 403, "message": "The request is missing a valid API key.", "errors": [ { "message": "The request is missing a valid API key.", "domain": "global", "reason": "forbidden" } ], "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED" } } in C:\xampp\htdocs\testingCalon\vendor\google\apiclient\src\Google\Http\REST.php:118 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\testingCalon\vendor\google\apiclient\src\Google\Http\REST.php(94): Google_Http_REST::decodeHttpResponse(Object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Response), Object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request), 'Google_Service_...') #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\testingCalon\vendor\google\apiclient\src\Google\Task\Runner.php(176): Google_Http_REST::doExecute(Object(GuzzleHttp\Client), Object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request), 'Google_Service_...') #2 C:\xampp\htdocs\testingCalon\vendor\google\apiclient\src\Google\Http\REST.php(58): Google_Task_Runner->run() #3 C:\xampp\htdocs\testingCalon\vendor\google\apiclient\src\Google\Client.php( in C:\xampp\htdocs\testingCalon\vendor\google\apiclient\src\Google\Http\REST.php on line 118

I follow the code that posting in google quickstart. but it come out with errors. [here](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/php)

Comment: Did you follow the Quickstart and setup carefully or did you modify things? That's weird because the sample doesn't make use of OAuth not API keys.

Comment: are u trying here to write or update? if it is re-authenticate the application and re-generate credentials.json